# Set value of TinyMCE editor pagesize plugin in angular

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have integrated TinyMCE editor with angular version eleven.

```
"@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.0.1"

<editor #editor [init]="tinyMCEConfigDraft" (onInit)="onEditorInit($event)" id="draftEditor"
                                [initialValue]="draftEditorContent" [(ngModel)]="draftEditorContent"
                                [disabled]="!editorEnabled" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                            </editor>
```

I have created pagesize plugin for editor.I want to set plugin value from angular by getting its value from rest api.I have tried that but that does not update the value of plugin.

```
   tinymce.activeEditor.fire('onPageSize', {value: draftModel.pageSize});
```

How can we set value of plugin from angular?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo?